# Deploying API through AWS CDK cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Message returned: AccessDeniedException: Resource is not in the state functionActive
at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:61:27)
at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:61:8)
at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request. (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12) (RequestId: e5e78188-41a5-48a7-acfb-7666448e88ef)

While deploying the stack from AWS CLI I got an error at step 108 of 112, it failed to deploy and the stack autmatically starts deleting. I added the necessary permissions to the CDK deploy ad execute role. But still getting the same error.

Any help regarding this?

Added the neccessary permissions like LambdaFullAccess, AdministartorAccess. But still getting this error

Comment: Could you provide a CDK example of what it is you're trying to deploy?

Comment: I have an API to deploy with a template and all the stacks and pre-defined with the the help of AWS CDK cloud formation.

Comment: It's almost impossible for us to help without seeing your code and being able to reproduce the issue.